# Parse SDK: How to clear Installation entry after user logs out or delete his account from app

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse to manage users and push notifications.

**But here is my problem:**

From the client app, when the user logs out his current account and logs in with a different account, the Parse SDK seems to be using the SAME `PFInstallation.currentInstallation()` entry, which belongs to the previous user!

The same thing happens when the user deletes his account then sign up with a new account, the PFInstallation entry from the Parse SDK is still the one from the previous deleted user!

How do we get a new `PFInstallation.currentInstallation()` entry so a brand new entry is used when a new user logs in or sign up right after a log out or delete account?

I'm having this issue with the Parse iOS SDK (1.10.0).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a column `isActive` to `Installation` class. And check in your Push code, value of this column.
2. Or you can add a pointer to `User` class, and when user logs out deletes account you query for installations related to this user and delete them.

Comment: Yes, but when a new user logs in, the PFInstallation.currentInstallation() is still the same entry as the one from the previous user. So i am just overwriting some information.. but it's not a completely new entry. The entry still belongs to the previous account.

Comment: Add `user` column to your `Installation` which will point to `User` who registered for push notifications. Then, when user logs out call `PFInstallation.currentInstallation().removeObjectForKey("user")`. And when you are sending pushes check that `user` field of installation isn't nil. It will guarantee that logged out users stop receiving notifications.

Comment: Ok, so all this means is that, there is **one** Installation entry that exists per device per app in Parse backend. So we just **update** the `user` pointer to reflect the new current logged in user. Every time someone logs out, and a different person logs in **on the same device**, we just update the installation entry with the new user.

Comment: I think this is still a problem, because let's say user A has in installation this custom property: "enalbedNewsletterPush" = true, then when he logs out, and a new user B logs in, that new user B will already have "enalbedNewsletterPush" = true .. so he basically inherits all previous values from the previous user A..

Comment: If there's such property then set it to `nil` or to `false` when user A logs out.

Comment: Parse themselves use such approach in their sample apps.

Comment: I think you are confusing users and devices.  The Apple Push Notification Service creates a token for a specific device.  The PFInstallation object, holds this token as a string value.  This connects your device and Parse's Push service.  A single iPhone and app can have multiple users.  What's important is that you connect the PFInstallation to the current user.  The PFInstallation is just the connection from Push to your device not to your users information.  Your code should handle what notifications are sent to each user.  PFInstallation just says if the road is open or closed.

Comment: @jonthornham you are right, I got confused between users and devices and the way i used the PFInstallation object was wrong (by putting user specific information in PFInstallation).